# What is the best program to modify the color of eyes?

Tags: software, post-processing, eyes

What is the best of the best program which lets me change the color of the eyes in a picture.

It doesn't matter if it is a free or shareware program.

Comment: Do you mean automatically, or a general-purpose photo-manipulation tool which will enable you to do this by hand?

Comment: Oh, and do you mean, for example, brown eyes to blue, or do you want to fix redeye?

Comment: that's it i want to change the color not to fix the red eyes.

Comment: What about the first question? (Do you want to "paint in" the new color, or have the software figure it out all by magic?)

Comment: i think that here are programs which make you to underline the color, i don't know .. like fixing some points and then make you to choose the color
because when you paint the new color it's sure that you cannot do it very well ..

Comment: If you want a post to get more attention, making substantive edits is welcome. It's even okay to make small edits to improve grammar and formatting. But please don't edit just to "bump" the post, and in general there's no need for signatures or greetings, as your name is attached automatically, and since as a QA site we assume polite greetings without needing 'em attached to every post. Thanks!

Comment: @mattdm greetins should automaticly be removed as discussed in this post on MetaSO http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple tutorial to modify the eye color in Photoshop: http://www.lunacore.com/photoshop/tutorials/tut004.htm

If you don't own photoshop, you can try the same thing in Gimp.

Comment: thank you this tutorial is very useful for my request thank you again

Answer (score 4):

If you are asking the best software regardless size or cost, Adobe Photoshop is always the best choice. If you are looking for something lighter, maybe you should try [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/).

Comment: yes i know photoshop is always the best and the difficult way to use.. 
But i think that Gimp will be useful for my request

thank you any way

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at [Portrait Professional](http://www.portraitprofessional.com/photo_editing_software/eyes_teeth_image_enhancement/) if you plan to do a lot of this. It's not super cheap but it does a ton of useful stuff for people photography. The link I provided is the the eye-color changing feature. There are heaps of other features in Portrait Pro. I typically just use Photoshop, but I also post-process only the smallest number of images from each shoot. If I were doing senior portraits or something like that, I'd certainly use this kind of tool.